# Store an array to each option in select control

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently building a dynamic select control as shown below,

```
targetSelectCtrl.empty().html(function () {
    var appendData ='';
    $.each(result, function (key, value) {
        appendData += "<option title = '" + value.Name +
                    "' value='" + value.Id +
                    "' data-positions=" + value.PositionsList +
                    " data-isactive='" + value.IsActive + "'>" +
                    value.Name + "</option>";
    });
    return appendData;
});
```

`value.PositionsList` is a javascript array object and I want to store that in each option.
I tried the above code and it did not work.

The idea is, whenever the user changes the option, I need the get the PositionsList to display in the webpage. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Why not build the HTML before the `html()` call? `var myHtml = /* gen html */; targetSelectCtrl.empty().html(myHtml);`

Comment: You can't just concat an array to a string. You have to create a string from it in anyway.

Comment: 'result' object comes from an ajax response. So, I am populating the select control dynamically, after I receive the response. At present, I am finding issues in setting the javascript object in data-positions attribute.

Comment: `it did not work`, what went wrong exactly? What output do you receive? For example, what does `console.log(appendData)` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try serializing the array as a JSON object. For example:

```
var appendData ='';

$.each(result, function (key, value) {
    // Encode as JSON:
    var serializedList = JSON.stringify(value.PositionsList);

    // Escape single quotes:
    serializedList = serializedList.replace(/'/g, "&#39;");

    appendData += "<option title = '" + value.Name+
                        "' value='" + value.Id+
                        "' data-positions='" + serializedList+
                        "' data-isactive='" + value.IsActive+ "'>" +
                        value.Name+ "</option>";

 });
```

Comment: Sure, going to try now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach, no need to encode/decode, you can use any object for PositionsList:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzq1tbw0/2/)

```
var targetSelectCtrl = $("select");
var result = [
    {Name:'name1',Id:'id',PositionsList:[1,2,3,4],IsActive:'.'},
    {Name:'name2',Id:'id',PositionsList:[1,2,3,4],IsActive:'.'}
    ];
targetSelectCtrl.empty();

var option;
$.each(result, function (key, value) {
    option = $("<option/>").attr({
        title:value.Name,
    }).html(value.Name).data({
        positions:value.PositionsList,
        isactive:value.IsActive
    });

    targetSelectCtrl.append(option);

});

targetSelectCtrl.change(function(e) {
    console.debug(" positons",$(e.target).find("option:selected").data('positions'));
});;
```